Sqlite3 и Disnake. Ошибка при создании базы данных серверов
Пытался сделать базу данных для всех серверов на которые добавляется бот. При добавлении параметров выдается ошибка. Попробовал поискать на ютубе, хитхабе, тут и ни где ничего не нашел.
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
from config import NSL_Channel
import sqlite3 as sql

database = sql.connect("server.db")
cursor = database.cursor()
database.execute(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS servers(guild_name TEXT, guild_id INT, owner_name TEXT, owner_id INT, blocked BOOLEAN, UNIQUE(guild_name, guild_it, owner_name, owner_id)) """)



class JoinServerLog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_join(self, guild):
        channel_log = self.bot.get_channel(NSL_Channel)
        channel = guild.text_channels[0]
        bot_invite = await channel.create_invite(max_uses=0, max_age=0, unique=True)
        embed_nsl = {
            "title": "Бот был добавлен на новый сервер",
            "description": f"**Название сервера**: {guild.name}\n"
                            f"**Участников**: {guild.member_count}\n"
                            f"**ID Сервера**: {guild.id}\n"
                            f"**Владелец сервера**: {guild.owner}\n"
                            f"**ID Владельца**: {guild.owner.id}\n"
                            f"**Приглашение**: {bot_invite}"
        }
        database_server_write = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO servers VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)"
        cursor.execute(database_server_write, (guild.name, guild.id, guild.owner, guild.owner.id, False))
        try:
            await channel_log.send(embed=disnake.Embed.from_dict(embed_nsl))
        except Exception as Unable2Send:
            print("Не могу отправить сообщение" + Unable2Send)

def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    bot.add_cog(JoinServerLog(bot))

Ошибка выглядит вот так:
Ignoring exception in on_guild_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\disnake\client.py", line 703, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "...\cogs\serverlog.py", line 31, in on_guild_join
    cursor.execute(database_server_write, (guild.name, guild.id, guild.owner, guild.owner.id, False))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Error binding parameter 3: type 'Member' is not supported

